# how to add form as data in class-base views?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I used to send form as content in `function-base-view` and I could use `for loop` to simply write down fields and values like:

```
{% for x in field %}
   <p>{{ x.label_tag }} : {{ x.value }} </p>
```

I don't remember whole the way so maybe I wrote it wrong but is there anyway to do this with `class-based-views`, because when I have many fields its really hard to write them 1by1

Comment: would you like to see how to declare a form class based on a model and make a view class based on that form?

Comment: yeah sounds a better way to understand

Comment: I'm just not quite sure what you really need either. You wrote to add a form as data, can you be more specific about what you want it to do?

Comment: in FBV i could call form that i used for adding a new object and add form into context of detail page, and in detail page i could call for fields values and label_tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure if this is what you need. But still I will try to answer. I took an example with [class AuthorDetail(FormMixin, DetailView)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#using-formmixin-with-detailview) as a basis. In get_context_data saved the form itself. In the template, first I displayed the form, then the value from the bbs model and requested
form.message.label_tag. To get the tag, I looked at this [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/api/).

In the class, replace the `Rubric` model with your own. In the template path: bboard/templ.html replace `bboard` with the name of your `application` where your templates are located.

views.py

```
class Dw(FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = Rubric
    template_name = 'bboard/templ.html'
    form_class = TestForm
    context_object_name = 'bbs'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Dw, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.get_form()
        print(77777, context['form']['message'].label_tag())

        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

forms.py

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    message = forms.CharField()
```

templates

```
<form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <input type="submit" value="adding">
</form>

<h2>{{ bbs }}</h2>
<h2>{{ form.message.label_tag }}</h2>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('<int:pk>/', Dw.as_view(), name='aaa'),
]
```

Comment: you solved my problem thank you , also can i use field with it instead of ```label_tag```?(to create ```for loop```